# How can I get into the boot menu without a keyboard?

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, bios

So my computer seems to be shot. I keep getting NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM blue-screen errors on startup. In an attempt to change a setting that would magically allow my computer to start up, I went into the BIOS and disabled USB before booting.

Now that I'm attempting to run memtest86 off of a disc, I've found that I can't actually get my computer to boot from the disc because I can't access the boot menu, because my keyboard no longer works before boot. I also don't have a PS/2 slot on my computer.

Is there any way to get to boot options without a keyboard?

I've tried holding down my power button while starting up, as I know some motherboards are set up to go into boot options that way. Mine just turns the computer off. I've also tried disconnecting the hard drive to see if it would automatically boot from the CD drive instead. It doesn't.

Comment: Reset the CMOS, either by moving a jumper cap or detaching and reattaching a CR battery on the motherboard. If the computer in question is a laptop, you may have to pry open the keyboard to access the CMOS battery.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Now to figure out what the hell is preventing my computer from starting.